# Dotnet ahead-of-time: PublishReadyToRun vs PublishAot vs RunAOTCompilation

Tags: c#, .net, aot

The recent dotnet version (dotnet 6 & 7) has an ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation feature. According to the official documentation, there are different approaches to achieving this.

[Native AOT Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[ReadyToRun Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[AOT Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup
```

It's quite hard to understand the concept by just reading the documentation.
What is the difference between the PublishReadyToRun vs PublishAot?
When to use one over the other? And how to enable AoT compilation for class libraries, blazor wasm, and asp.net core projects?

Comment: Found some useful information on this topic: https://github.com/carlfranklin/Native-AOT-Test

Comment: RTR and AOT both precompile the assemblies in the project.  But big difference, AOT must precompile *everything*, RTR still allows the just-in-time compiler to run to deal with code that could not correctly be precompiled.  Reflection is the common example, AOT cannot properly detect types being used that way.  Which is why you can't use AOT on WPF or Winforms projects.  Select AOT for platform targets that require it, like Apple mobile devices.

Answer (score 6):

AOT means: the compiler will generate a native code executable, and the application can run on a machine that doesn't have the .NET runtime installed.

R2R compilation is "part AOT". Your application will need .NET runtime to be installed to run. But, the startup performance is improved, compared to fully .net binary.

Comment: You do not need .NET runtime installed if you use self-contained publishing. It includes all necessary .NET runtime assemblies and services side-by-side with your application assemblies.
In fact, ReadyToRun is a startup time optimization. It compiles as many methods as it can into platform-specific native code and places it along with MSIL and type metadata. MSIL is still needed by JIT for methods that can't be compiled during the R2R phase.